# Stop a Symfony Console command

Tags: symfony, console, command

I have a Symfony console command that loops continuously

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
   //... 

   pcntl_signal(SIGHUP, [$this, 'stopCommand']);

    $this->shouldStop = false;

    while (true) {


        pcntl_signal_dispatch();

        if ($this->shouldStop) {
            break;
        }
        sleep(60);
    }
}

protected function stopCommand()
{
    $this->shouldStop = true;
}
```

I wish I could stop him from a controller

```
    public function stopAction()
{ 
    posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGHUP);

    return new Response('ok');
}
```

but I do not know why it does not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably does not work, because console command is running in different process than controller action. Try to store PID number of console command into the file at the beginning of execution with something like:

```
file_put_contents("/tmp/console_command.pid", posix_getpid());
```

and then use this code in controller:

```
posix_kill(file_get_contents("/tmp/console_command.pid"), SIGHUP);
```